# T SQL Datepart and Count - Show also weeks with zero count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, datepart

I have following SQL statement:

```
declare @dateFrom datetime = '2015-01-01'; 
declare @dateTo datetime = '2015-12-31'; 

select 
    DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate) Week, Count(*) Number
from 
    table 
where 
    OrderDate between @dateFrom and @dateTo 
group by 
    DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate) 
order by 
    Week
```

It returns the number of orders per week, but if there were no orders at all this respective week is omitted.

How can I change the statement so it will also include weeks with 0 orders?

Comment: Do you have a time table containing relevant dates?

Comment: @sagi what do you mean with 'relevant dates'? I want the counts for all weeks over a year even if it is zero

Answer (score 2):

Gofr1 was on the right track but there are issues with the query.

1 - You do not want to use the datediff() of the begin and end as the stopping condition.  It works for a whole year but will not work for partial ranges.

2 - I would add year to the key since that will allow you to handle cross year cases.

3 - You need to roll up the sales before using the Year Week Common Table Expression.  Otherwise you just toss out the nulls again (order dates) with the WHERE clause.

Remember, logically the join is applied then the where clause.

The code below uses the Adventure Works 2012 DW database and obtains the correct answer.

- Uses a tally table for some numbers.
- Generates weekly dates and calculates year/week key for given range.
- Rolls up sales from the fact table for given range.
- Left joins the keys to the sales and turns null totals to zero.

Code:

```
-- Declare start and end date
DECLARE @dte_From datetime = '2005-07-01'; 
DECLARE @dte_To datetime = '2007-12-31'; 

-- About 200K numbers
WITH cte_Tally (n) as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.all_views a 
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_views b
),

-- Create year/week key
cte_YearWeekKey (MyKey) as
(
SELECT 
    year(dateadd(week, t.n, @dte_from)) * 1000 + 
    datepart(week, dateadd(week, t.n, @dte_from)) as MyKey
FROM 
    cte_Tally as t
WHERE 
    dateadd(week, t.n, @dte_from) < @dte_To
),

-- Must roll up here
cte_Sales (MyKey, MyTotal) as
(
SELECT 
    YEAR(F.OrderDate) * 1000 +
    DATEPART(WEEK, F.OrderDate) as MyKey, 
    COUNT(*) as MyTotal
FROM
    [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[FactResellerSales] F
WHERE 
    F.OrderDate between @dte_From and @dte_To 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(F.OrderDate) * 1000 +
    DATEPART(WEEK, F.OrderDate)
)

-- Join the results
SELECT 
    K.MyKey, ISNULL(S.MyTotal, 0) as Total
FROM
    cte_YearWeekKey as K
LEFT JOIN 
    cte_Sales as S
ON 
    k.MyKey = S.MyKey
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems much more accurate so I delete mine :) Take an upvote!

Comment: Just one more comment.  Since you will never need 200k numbers, cross sys.types with sys.all_views to come up with 14.5K  numbers.  This will help with overall execution time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really thought there is an easier way in SQL...seems I was wrong :) I will adopt your approach

Comment: One way to make it faster is to create a static table that has yyyyww for all weeks of interest.  That will eliminate the first two common table expressions.  Maybe add a key.  Again, keys on small tables might not improve performance since the table can be read into memory (pages).  In short, you always have to use a driver table that has data to join to a table (grouping) that might not.